# GitOps deployment with ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, argocd, gitops

I am looking at ArgoCD for Kubernetes to deploy the applications in GitOps way.

Just wondering if there are any similar products available for AWS ECS and Hashicorp Nomad.

I know about AWS Proton, it is not as simple as ArgoCD. For AWS ECS, I am just looking for some tool that can read the ECS Task Definition and Service Definition and sync it with AWS ECS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub Actions for that!
There is a GitHub Action that makes this setup very easy: `amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition`

And you can configure the workflow to be triggered on every push or merged PR. This is what I am using at my company and works pretty well.

Documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-amazon-elastic-container-service

Comment: This isn't what gitops is. For gitops AWS needs to pull the configuration from a git repo

Comment: The difference here being that there's no component like ArgoCD or Flux doing the diff between the deployed config and the desired configuration. GitHub Actions could be made to do that and it would be GitOps - there's no need for AWS to be the component doing the pull.

Comment: Coming from this angle, it just doesn't matter what tooling you use. It may be Jenkins, Giltlab, Github Actions or any other tooling. In this model it is a push-based approach, where resources are getting created by CI/CD to resemble a target state.Yet, if the target state deviates, the CI/CD pipeline component be it any of the named above (Jenkins, GH Actions, etc.) will do no diff-check.
In the GitOps model, a tool like flux/ArgoCD do a diff-checking of the target environment and derive actions to create the desired target state. Also, this has the effect no credentials are needed in CI/CD.